# UINavigationItem rightbarbuttonitem not displaying

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

As my title, I have went through several websites and failed to achieve the result. However, I managed to add an image on the navigation bar successfully. These are two problems I'm facing currently, both are under UINavigationBar section. 
1. Unable to display the rightbarbutton
2. Unable to hide the back arrow "<"

MasterViewController.m

```
//Back Button
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sidemenu.png"];
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);

//Rightbarbutton
UIButton *infoButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_info.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButtonItem;

//Image (Working and displaying)
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"icon_image.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 0, 30, 42)];
[imageView setImage:image];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your UINavigationItem+AtAdditions.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ATNavigationItemButtonSide) {
    ATNavigationItemButtonSideRight,
    ATNavigationItemButtonSideLeft
};

@interface UINavigationItem(ATAdditions)

// This method adds an image-only button to the requested size (right or left) of the current navigation item, the image can't be tapped
- (void)addColorfulImage:(NSString*)imageName toSide:(ATNavigationItemButtonSide)side;

@end
```

This is your UINavigationItem+AtAdditions.m file

```
#import "UINavigationItem+ATAdditions.h"

@implementation UINavigationItem(ATAdditions)

- (void)addColorfulImage:(NSString*)imageName toSide:(ATNavigationItemButtonSide)side {
    // Create a button with the required image on it
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Stop the events (it's an image only)
    button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    // Add the button to the navigation item
    if (side == ATNavigationItemButtonSideLeft) {
        self.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    }
    else if (side == ATNavigationItemButtonSideRight) {
        self.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    }
}

@end
```

Later you can import the .h file and use it on the navigation item in your view controller.

Comment: Is that bringSubviewToFront? As I just got "No visible @interface for 'UINavigationBar' declares the selector 'bringSubviewToBack:".

Comment: Okay try the code I added, I built this a while ago but I guess it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize you rightItem's content as an UIButton and not a cast from ImageView to UIButton... so the same procedure you are doing for the back item..